# Error while trying to implement oAuth with Google in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-oauth

I am trying to implement **Login with Google** into my web based application developed in vb.net. I am using VS2013 with Telerik controls. Unfortunately, there is no useful example available for vb.net and **Google** themselves seems reluctant to put one for the vb.net. I have a Login Button that allows user to Login to my application via their existing Google Account. Following is the code for the same.

```
Protected Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    Dim clientID As String = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    Dim clientSecret As String = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

    Dim scopes As String() = New String() {Google.Apis.Plus.v1.PlusService.Scope.UserinfoEmail}

    Dim credential As UserCredential 
    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(New ClientSecrets() With {.ClientId = clientID, .ClientSecret = clientSecret}, scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None, New FileDataStore("Drive.Auth.Store")).Result
End Sub
```

In spite of double checking everything, I keep getting the 'redirect_uri_mismatch' error. Following is the snapshot of the error.
[image: Error while trying to Login]

I have read lots of documentation on this and as it suggest, it is an error with redirect URL to be configured in the Google developer's console but as far I have concern, I think it is correctly configured. Here is the snapshot of my Google console's Client ID.

[image]

And here is the Snapshot of my request origin.
[image]

I will greatly appreciate if anyone has the knowledge and willing to share on this issue as it is really driving me crazy.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can call the authentication URL like the following , which is i used for `Calender API`

```
Dim Uri As String = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=" & clientId & "&redirect_uri=" & redirecturi & "&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar&login_hint=" & mainUser & "&include_granted_scopes=true"
        Response.Redirect(Uri)
```

you have to give appropriate values for  :

clientId,mainUser,redirecturi. where,
`mainUser`  is the mail id which is used for authentication,
`redirecturi` is the URI of our site/ page their we handles the response. and it must be same in the passing url and also in the developer console

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/869770/Handling-events-in-google-calendar-using-google

Comment: Many Thanks @Poornima. I will look into the code and see if my problem could be resolved from this. Many Thanks again.

Comment: if it seems use full then support my friend in code project

Comment: it seems to work but this is not what I am looking for. I only need user's email id from the scope Google.Apis.Plus.v1.PlusService.Scope.UserinfoEmail. While your method works for calendar and works well but this method requires knowing of user's email id before hand.